# Accessing a dict in a List (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The following is my code:

```
user=[]
new_user={"User_Name" : input("Choose your Username: "),
              "Name" : input("Enter your Name: "),
              "Surname": input("Enter your Surname: "),
              "Password" : input("Choose your password: "),
              "Birthdate" : input("Enter your Birthdate: "),
              "Adress" : input("Enter your adress: "),
              "Activity" : input("What's your favorite Activity?: "),
              }
user.append(new_user)
```

And I wanted to check whether the password which was input was in the list, so I went for:

```
password = input("Password: ")
if password in user:
   print("logged in")
else:
   print("log-in failed")
```

And even though the password I typed in for the new_user and the password I typed in for the "if-condition" check were equal, it didn't work. (I always got "log_in failed".)

If you need further information to help me, please let me know.

Comment: `if password in user[0]['Password']` ?

Comment: .. which would not be working fine if you have multiple entries in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if condition does not resolve to True because you are checking if a string is contained in a list of dictionaries. It will always be False.
Assuming that the user list would eventually grow to be bigger than 1 item. Then the best approach would be to do this:

```py
logged_in = False

for dic in user:
    if dic['Password'] == password:
        logged_in = True

if logged_in:
    print("logged in")
else:
    print("log-in failed")
```

Comment: Thank you. It has been fixed

Comment: Thanks buddy, this was the perfect solution to my problem.
Thanks for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 1):

```
users=[]
new_user={"User_Name" : input("Choose your Username: "),
              "Name" : input("Enter your Name: "),
              "Surname": input("Enter your Surname: "),
              "Password" : input("Choose your password: "),
              "Birthdate" : input("Enter your Birthdate: "),
              "Adress" : input("Enter your adress: "),
              "Activity" : input("What's your favorite Activity?: "),
              }
users.append(new_user)

password = input("Password: ")
if password in [user["Password"] for user in users]:
   print("logged in")
else:
   print("log-in failed")
```

Relevant line: `if password in [user["Password"] for user in users]`

I assume you don't want a simple `==` comparison since you did `if .. in ..`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if password in user[0]["Password"]`, which gives you :

```
password = input("Password: ")
if password in user[0]["Password"]:
   print("logged in")
else:
   print("log-in failed")
```

**EDIT**

With user + password :

```
users=[]
user_1={
    "User_Name" : "a",
    "Password" : "aa"
}
users.append(user_1)
user_2={
    "User_Name" : "b",
    "Password" : "bb"
}
users.append(user_2)

username = input("User name: ")
password = input("Password: ")
logged_in = False
for u in users:
    if u["User_Name"] == username and u["Password"] == password:
        print("logged in")
        logged_in = True
if not logged_in:
   print("log-in failed")
```

Comment: I already tried this one before and it worked, but as I change some things (I just added a few users), I always had to use the password of the last user that I created.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: If you have multiple users, then you should ask for more than just the password. I advise you to ask for `username` + `password` (see my edited answer)

Comment: This works, it's quite like the answer of @Chief Oye, with the boolean check. And yea, with multiple users, I gotta check more than just the password, but I was trying to get a simple answer / short answer for only this problem (so I can think myself into it a little and get the solution for checking the username etc. myself).
But I really appreciate your Effort in helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be:

```
password = input("Password: ")
if password == user[0]["Password"]:
   print("logged in")
else:
   print("log-in failed")
```

The check `if password in user` just checks if the password is in the dictionnary keys (i.e. `"User_Name"`, `"Name"`, `"Surname"`, ...)

Comment: I have just tried this, and as I expected, it only works with one user (the first user basically). As I added some more users, I always had to use (or moreless could use) the password which I first typed. This solution works good if I want to have a master password, so I will be using this, as my programm grows bigger.
Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to achieve this result:

```
users=[]
new_user={"User_Name" : input("Choose your Username: "),
          "Name" : input("Enter your Name: "),
          "Surname": input("Enter your Surname: "),
          "Password" : input("Choose your password: "),
          "Birthdate" : input("Enter your Birthdate: "),
          "Adress" : input("Enter your adress: "),
          "Activity" : input("What's your favorite Activity?: "),
          }
users.append(new_user)

print("users list:")
print(users)

def login(password):
    for user in users:
        if password == user['Password']:
            return "logged in"
    return "log-in failed"

print("\tTest using wrong password:")
print(login("a_password"))
print("\nTest using good password:")
print(login("test_password"))
```

**Output**

```
users list:
[{'Activity': 'my_activity', 'Surname': 'my_surname', 'User_Name': 'my_username', 'Adress': 'my_address', 'Birthdate': 'my_birthdate', 'Name': 'my_name', 'Password': 'my_password'}]

Test using wrong password:
log-in failed

Test using good password:
logged in
```

**Explanation**
In order to access a user's password you need to take into account that here you are building a list of users.
If you want to be able to better understand what I am saying visualizing data please read carefully the `print(users)` result in the output.
To access a specific user's password iteration is mandatory, this is why I use a for loop in the login function.
Once I have the user (user1, user2, user3...) it is easy to access  its password field and check if it matches the input using user['Password'].

**Note**
I also suggest to use **==** instead of **in** because:
`"mickey" in "mickey mouse"` will evaluate as **true**
`"mickey" in "mickey"` will evaluate as **true**
`"mickey" == "mickey"` will evaluate as **true** (must be 100% matching)
`"mickey" == "mickey mouse"` will evaluate as **false**